# Scheduling events in Spring

Tags: spring

I'm using Spring MVC+Spring Data with a Relational DB for a web application.
What I need to do is to trigger a check at midnight. In particular, I need to go through a list of persistent objects and check whether they expire on the just-started day.

Also, I would like to schedule some events at given intervals (e.g. once a week).

Does Spring offer a support for that?

EDIT: My solution

```
@Service
public class MyWork implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        workToDo();
    }


    private void workToDo()  { /*do it*/}
}

@Service
public class MySchedulerInvoker {
    @Autowired
    private TaskScheduler scheduler;

    @Async
    public void executeTask() {
    scheduler.schedule(new MyWork(), new CronTrigger(
            "* 15 9-17 * * MON-FRI"));
}
```

Comment: Of course it does, since Spring 1.0: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.5/reference/scheduling.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does and its pretty easy to use - checkout [Sprint Tasks Execution and Scheduling](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html)

Comment: Thanks. I created a Class implementing Runnable called MyWork. Then I created another class, annotated with "Service". In this class, I created a field @Autowired TaskScheduler scheduler; and a method annotated with "Async" which invokes scheduler.schedule(new MyWork(), new CronTrigger("15 7 * * *")). Do I need to do anything else to make MyWork run every day a 7.15 in the morning? E.g. configuration files, installing cron etc...

Comment: A Trigger is probably what you need I think. From the link above: "For example the following task is being scheduled to run 15 minutes past each hour but only during the 9-to-5 "business hours" on weekdays.

scheduler.schedule(task, new CronTrigger("* 15 9-17 * * MON-FRI"));"

Comment: That may be a bit hard to read - I suggest going to the Spring link again and search for CronTrigger :-)

Comment: You could also configure this in your spring config files:  <task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="anotherObject" method="anotherMethod" cron="*/5 * * * * MON-FRI"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>

Comment: It is not really clear to me how the scheduler i caught by Spring: how does the directive "task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler" know the type of scheduler I want?